# NSIntersectionRange with a 0 length argument

Tags: objective-c, nsrange

In Objective C, when using the function NSIntersectionRange with one of the arguments being zero length, does the result equal the other argument? Didn't see this when I searched so I wanted to clarify it for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it returns the argument that was not 0 length.